# Is it possible to show only the bottom and left axes in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to remove the top and right axes in this graph:

### [image]

Here is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
xlabel={Time},
ylabel={Stock Price},
xticklabels={,,}
]
\addplot[line width=1pt,solid,color=blue] %
table[col sep=comma]{stock1.csv};
\addplot[line width=1pt,solid,color=orange] %
table[col sep=comma]{stock2.csv};
\addplot[line width=1pt,solid,color=red] %
table[col sep=comma]{stock3.csv};
\end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is covered in the tutorial part of the `pgfplots` manual (`axis lines=left`): I'm not sure if that is what you are after?

Comment: Depending on your data, i.e. depending on whether the `t` values start at 0, `axis lines=middle` may be what you're looking for.